# jQuery next() does not return next sibling with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my HTML

```
</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ServiceLocationActive" name="ServiceLocationActive" checked="" value="false">
    <span class="toggle"></span>
    <span class="toggle-text">Active</span>
<label>
```

this is my JavaScript

```
$('#ServiceLocationActive').on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        $(this).next('.toggle-text').html('Active');
    else
        $(this).next('.toggle-text').html('Inactive');
});
```

The problem is that the next does not return anything. If I try to use only `.next()` I will get the first span but if I use `.next('.toggle-text')` I won't get anything. Further absurde is if I use `next().next()` I will get the lement I want.

What is happening here?

Comment: That's exactly how `next` is intended to work:`Get the immediately following sibling`, use [`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) or [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) instead

Comment: Could have answered this yourself by reading the [next() api docs](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

Comment: If a jQuery method isn't doing what you expect then look at the documentation for that method (similarly with regular JavaScript methods and functions), most of the time it's doing exactly what it should do, just not what you expected.

Comment: @charlietfl I did read the docs. I guess the third example got me confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.next()` returns immediately following siblings and the element `.toggle` element not `.toggle-text` element.

You can use `.siblings()`

```
 $(this).siblings('.toggle-text')
```